# Как можно программно идентифицировать элементы интерфейса ОС и программ - ярлыки, кнопки и т.п.?

Tags: c#

Подумываю замахнуться на масштабный проектик - программу для автоматизации приложений и ОС (масштабный для моего уровня - всего два месяца с момента начала обучения).

В принципе, большую часть нужной инфы уже нашел, загвоздка только с одним моментом. Софта для автоматизации существует целая гора, и в некоторых программах, которые довелось попробовать (например, Power Automate Desktop) есть функция считывания и записи в виде команд действий пользователя, при этом при наведении курсора мыши на объекты на экране (ярлыки, кнопки, поля для ввода текста и т.п.) эти объекты выделяются рамкой по периметру, т.е. идентифицируются не просто как изображение на экране, а именно как элементы.

Прошу подсказать, как это осуществляется, и можно ли встроить такой же функционал в программу на c#. Может есть какая-то библиотека, в которой содержатся нужные методы?

Также буду признателен за любые советы, которые могут пригодиться в реализации подобного проекта.

Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не все приложения можно автоматизировать [через API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55129774/12888024). Поэтому я бы ещё про компьютерное зрение и нейронки что-то поизучал. Симуляция мышеклавы - это просто.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Значит, по поводу моего вопроса - копать в сторону API? По поводу того, что это пододет не для всех приложений я в курсе, так как уже кучу подобного софта перепробовал, и сформировал определенный перечень требований к программе. Помимо распознавания элементов интерфейса она должна уметь "фоткать" на экране нужные элементы (кнопки, например), и затем уметь находить их. Должна уметь ждать определенные события (открытие нужного окна), а также компилировать итоговый результат в исполняемый файл. В целом, это самые важные функции. И всё это в графическом интерфейсе.